# E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages - libpq-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I'm trying to install libpq-dev yet receiving an error while trying to do that.

When I run:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

I receive the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 9.5.5-0ubuntu0.16.04) but 9.6.0-1 is to be    installed
             Depends: krb5-multidev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I run `apt-cache policy libpq5`:

```
libpq5:
  Installed: 9.6.0-1
  Candidate: 9.6.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 9.6.0-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     9.5.5-0ubuntu0.16.04 500
        500 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     9.5.4-0ubuntu0.16.04 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     9.5.2-1 500
        500 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: do `sudo apt-get -f install libpq-dev` and see if it help fix broken package.

Comment: Tried doing that, receiving same error exactly

Comment: please do `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Have tried this one also now.. yet the same error persist..

Comment: If you'd like post results of `apt-cache policy libpq5` I'd say you got libpq5 from a ppa or elsewhere as 9.6.0-1 is not in Ubuntu. So basically wherever you acquired libpq5-9.6.0-1 is where you'd need to get the matching -dev package.

Comment: @doug I have added the requested results..

Comment: No real idea where you got it from, maybe from Debian some time ago as current is 9.6.1-2. So your best bet is to `sudo apt purge libpq5` , then re-install using Ubuntu package. Generally a poor idea to install packages from Debian repos in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `libpq-dev` package required `libpq5` `9.5.5-0` version, while you has `9.6.0-1` version. You have to force downgrade of `libpq5` package:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq5=9.5.5-0ubuntu0.16.04
```

Followed by `krb5-multidev` installation:

```
sudo apt-get install krb5-multidev
```

#### Update

I don't know why this hapening, but if you download both `libkrb5-3` and `libgssapi-krb5-2` from terminal by default it will install the `1.13.2+dfsg-5` version. Apply previous method to resolve this issue:

```
sudo apt-get install libgssapi-krb5-2=1.13.2+dfsg-5
sudo apt-get install libkrb5-3=1.13.2+dfsg-5
```

Comment: I have managed to run successfully the first, yet the second gives the following error: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 krb5-multidev : Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.14.3+dfsg-2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.13.2+dfsg-5) but 1.14.3+dfsg-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: @peterrobertlzlz Edited.

Comment: did what you offered, received error for the first cause it depends on the second. Did the second and it said it is dependent on `libkrb5support0`..  I did a `sudo apt-get install libkrb5support0` and it removed **tons** of packages and now my machine is not working..

Comment: Was you trying to install postgreql ?

Comment: Yes, I did not expect that it will break my installation..

Comment: Installation is simple as `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib`, what went wrong?

Comment: Whats gone wrong is he has mixed Debian packages & possibly some 16.10 packages into a 16.04 install.  A self created potential mess..